# fixing google minify css url screwup

Tags: css, url, minify

so I'm using google's minify to minify css:

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

what I notice is that google minify replaces the relative urls for background-images to the docroot...
but then since the code is called using docroot/min/f=something, this would break the background images since instead of calling it from docroot/images, the correct thing to do is to call if from ../images

is there a way to configure minify as to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a page about URL Rewriting in the project's wiki — http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UriRewriting

You can disable the magnification at all: `$min_serveOptions['rewriteCssUris'] = false;`, or, if you want to use this optimization on other links, maybe the section “Document Root Confusion” of this wiki page would be helpful.